# Static FIFO queue with timer c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a .NET 4.0 ASP.NET project which requires some threading work I've never really messed with before and I've been looking at this for days and I'm still clueless =/

Basically I want something like when you take a ticket at the deli and wait your turn before they get back to you.  I'll try and relate this and see if it makes any sense...

function starts ---> gets to section where it needs to "take a ticket" (I assume queue some type of item in a blockingcollection) and waits until other "tickets" (a.k.a other instances of the same function) are completed before it gives the function the OK to resume (blocking collection gets to the item in the queue) ---> finish function.

I don't need/want to do any work in the queue, I just want the function to statically wait it's turn among other instances of the function. Does that make sense?  Is that possible?

Please provide code if possible as I've seen tons of examples but none of them make sense/don't do what I want.

Comment: Alright so after reading some more I definitely think the BlockingCollection seems like the best idea, although I don't see way to use in such a way that it will just return back the to producer class once the item that was queued for that specific thread is dequeued.  Something around the AutoResetEvent.WaitOne perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so after researching document after document and playing with numerous rewrites of code I finally figured out I wasn't using the AutoResetEvent right and how to use a blocking collection on a dedicated thread.  So here was the final solution using an AutoResetEvent with a BlockingCollection.  This solution below might not show the same results 100% of the time (just because I believe it has to do with thread timing of when something was entered into the blocking collection) but the end result is that it does exactly what I want.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TaskProcessor tp = new TaskProcessor();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(tp.SubmitRequest));
        t1.Start(1);

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(tp.SubmitRequest));
        t2.Start(2);

        Thread t3 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(tp.SubmitRequest));
        t3.Start(3);         
    }
}

class TaskProcessor
{
    private AutoResetEvent _Ticket;

    public TaskProcessor()
    {
        _Continue = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    }

    public void SubmitRequest(object i)
    {
        TicketingQueue dt = new TicketingQueue();

        Console.WriteLine("Grab ticket for customer {0}", (int)i);

        dt.GrabTicket(_Ticket);

        _Continue.WaitOne();

        Console.WriteLine("Customer {0}'s turn", (int)i);
    }
}

public class TicketingQueue
{
    private static BlockingCollection<AutoResetEvent> tickets = new BlockingCollection<AutoResetEvent>();

    static TicketingQueue()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(
          () =>
          {
              while (true)
              {                      
                  AutoResetEvent e = tickets.Take();
                  e.Set();
                  Thread.Sleep(1000);
              }
          });
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void GrabTicket(AutoResetEvent e)
    {
        tickets.Add(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the timer solution, I'd enqueue all operations into a BlockingCollection and have a dedicated thread dequeue them. This thread would wait 5s and then push the dequeued item onto the thread pool. This dedicated thread should do this in an infinite loop. Dequeue, wait, push.

What I actually recommend however, is that you use the SemaphoreSlim class to throttle the number of concurrent requests to this fragile web service. Probably you should pick a number between 1 and 5 or so as the allowed amount of concurrency.

Comment: Yeah I saw the use of the blocking solution on a dedicated thread here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811365/conditionally-run-the-methods-of-a-class-on-a-separate-thread but I didn't how to do it synchronously

Comment: I understand. You want the issuer of the IO to wait for the IO to complete. You can do that by creating a ManualResetEventSlim which you enqueue together with the IO request. Once the IO has been completed (on the thread-pool) it needs to set this event. The original issuer of the IO can .Wait() on that event. All of this communication comes at a performance cost but as we are talking about single-digit requests per second it does not matter at all.